# Convert different unicode styles / Test for unicode-string in bash

Tags: bash, unicode, encoding, utf-8, iconv

I have a big text file with different entries, some are just plain ASCII, some are UTF-8 and some are like double-UTF-8.

Here's the content of the file as `cat` shows it:

```
'BÃÂ¶ker'
'fÃ¼r'
```

And here's what `less` would show:

```
'BÃ<U+0083>Â¶ker'
'fÃ¼r'
```

This is what I would like to get (clean ISO-8859-1):

```
'Böker'
'für'
```

Using `iconv --from-code=UTF-8 --to-code=ISO-8859-1` this is the result:

```
'BÃ¶ker'
'für'
```

Using `iconv --from-code=UTF-8 --to-code=ISO-8859-1` **twice** (with the same parameters), it gives the correct ö, but interprets the ü as well (output from `less`):

```
'Böker'
'f<FC>r'
```

One approach would be to test every string in `bash` which unicode format it currently is in. I searched quite a lot for this, but couldn't find a suitable answer.

Another approach would be to have a program that converts the strings directly to the correct format, but I couldn't find another program like iconv, and since <FC> is a perfectly valid character in ISO-8859-1, neither using "-c" nor adding "//IGNORE" to the -to-code change the output.

Comment: _double-UTF-8_ - this is not a thing. `BÃ<U+0083>Â¶ker` - this seems to imply that ö is four octets wide. But I struggle to see how you'd get the visible graphemes from either UTF-32 or GB18030. In UTF-8 it would either be two bytes wide or three if it was [normalized](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/) to NFD. Transcoding can be lossy (and destructive if you decode using the wrong encoding.) If this data is the result of a buggy transform then the correct state may be unrecoverable.

Comment: I know it's not a correct encoding and only tried to describe what is happening. This will reproduce the same value for the ö: `echo "ö" | iconv --from-code=ISO8859-1 --to-code=UTF-8 | iconv --from-code=ISO8859-1 --to-code=UTF-8`. I get the input value as they are and have no influence how they were created. Is there at least a way to test whether the characters must still be decoded?

Comment: The best you can do is try an [encoding detection API](http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion/detection) but these are inherently unreliable. With "plain text" you must know the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to solve this in a general way (what if 'BÃ¶ker' as well as 'Böker' could be valid input?) but usually you can find a heuristic that works for your data. Since you seem to have only or mostly German-language strings, the problematic characters are `ÄÖÜäöüß`. One approach would be to search every entry for these characters in ISO-8859-1, UTF-8 and double encoded UTF-8. If a match is found, simply assume that this is correct encoding.

If you're using `bash`, you can grep for the byte sequences using the `$'\xnn'` syntax. You only have to make sure that `grep` uses the `C` locale. Here's an example for the character `ö` (output from a UTF-8 console):

```
$ cat test.txt
B▒ker ISO-8859-1
Böker UTF-8
BÃ¶ker Double encoded UTF-8
$ LC_ALL=C grep $'\xF6' test.txt
B▒ker ISO-8859-1
$ LC_ALL=C grep $'\xC3\xB6' test.txt
Böker UTF-8
$ LC_ALL=C grep $'\xC3\x83\xC2\xB6' test.txt
BÃ¶ker Double encoded UTF-8
```

But it's probably easier to solve this with a scripting language like Perl or Python.